# Creating a histogram in R with random numbers [1-5] from a .csv file

Tags: r, csv

I'm new with R, but doing my best..

I'm trying to create a histogram from data I got in a .csv file. Just imagine one column with 10.000 random numbers with a range from 1 to 5. I want to create a histogram that shows how many times 1 occurs, how many times 2 occurs, how many times 3 occurs, etc. (Up to 5).

Is this possible in any way? Or should I do this in Excel and then get the results from there into R to create the histogram? I don't seem to get any wiser from any of the video tutorials so far or any of the other questions asked on here..

Comment: Histograms can be made with the `hist` function. For example, `x = runif(100); hist(x)` will make a histogram of `x` (which in this case is 100 numbers between 0 and 1). You can use `??histogram` from within R to try find functions to do with histograms.

Answer (score 1):

Import data from csv into R first:

```
dat = read.csv("c:\\documents\\file.csv")
```

Assuming you have a column called "col" in your csv file that has your data, run this:

```
hist(dat$col)
```

If you need to know how many times each value occurs, a more precise way is to make a table:

```
table(dat$col)
```